# Is there a Game Over?

Tags: realm-of-empires

Will there be anytime where I will be "Game Over"? That I will have to start back from nothing, because I lost everything or someone ended the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Unlike other popular MMORTS, you can lose your whole empire and then you are out of the world, assuming the world is closed by then. If it is not yet closed, then you will start again on the rim of the world.